# Space complexity of a recursive algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, space-complexity

I have a recursive algorithm to find a palindrome in Java. It should return true if the given string is palindrome. False otherwise. This method uses substring method, which is little bit trickier to find the complexity.

Here's my algorithm:

```
static boolean isPalindrome (String str) {
    if (str.length() > 1) {
        if (str.charAt(0) == (str.charAt(str.length() - 1))) {
    if (str.length() == 2) return true;
            return isPalindrome(str.substring(1, str.length() - 1));
        }
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

What is the space complexity of this algorithm ?

I mean, when I call the method `substring()`, does it create a new string all the time ? What actually `substring` method do in Java ?

Comment: [Here's](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/String.java#String.substring%28int%29) the source code. See for yourself.

Comment: As of OpenJDK 7u6, `substring` creates a completely new copy and takes O(n) time; you'd probably be better off having an overload accepting a start and end index.

Comment: Looks like a `O(n)` construction of a new string unless the substring asked for is already the full String.

Comment: Thank you @SotiriosDelimanolis ....... as it seems, it will increase the time complexity. Have to do better.

Comment: A simpler solution -- and one that handles the Unicode surrogate pairs correctly -- is to call `StringBuilder#reverse()` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse() then compare to the input string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In older versions of Java ([mainly in Java 6 and before](http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/))*, `substring` returned a new instance that shared the internal `char` array of the longer string (that is nicely illustrated  [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/the-substring-method-in-jdk-6-and-jdk-7/)). Then `substring` had time and a space complexity of **O(1)**.

Newer versions use a different representation of `String`, which does not rely on a shared array. Instead, `substring` allocates a new array of just the required size, and copies the contents from the longer string. Then `substring` has a time and a space complexity of **O(n)**.

<sub>*Actually the change was introduced in update 6 of Java 7.</sub>